# How to display loaded posts with React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, wordpress-rest-api

I'm new to React and Redux, and im trying to load posts from the WordPress REST API, and display them in my React App.

I'm using this as an example: https://github.com/jackreichert/a-wp-react-redux-theme

My action to get the posts look like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_POSTS = 'FETCH_POSTS';

export function fetchPosts(post_type = 'posts') {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/wp-json/wp/v2/${post_type}`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_POSTS,
                    payload: response.data
                });
            });
    }
}
```

It's passed to the reducer, which looks like this:

```
import { FETCH_POSTS } from '../actions';

export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_POSTS:
            return action.payload;
        default :
            state = '';
        break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

And (though it's only one reducer) I'm combining it, because there are more reducers to follow (just like in the example), and then I'm storing it. Also pretty much the same way as the example.

Im loading everything in my `Home.jsx` file, which looks like this right now:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from '../Header';
import {fetchPosts} from '../../actions/';

class Home extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        document.title = 'Test';
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getPosts(this.props, true);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.getPosts(nextProps);
    }

    getPosts(props, willMount = false) {
        if (willMount) {
            this.props.fetchPosts();
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <main>
                  <h1>Home</h1>
                </main>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({posts}) {
    return {posts};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPosts})(Home);
```

I think my code above is right. Redux can also 'find' my posts, and logs in my console:

```
action FETCH_POSTS @ 11:11:56.393
    prev state Object {posts: ""}
    action     Object {type: "FETCH_POSTS", payload: Array(2)}
    next state Object {posts: Array(2)}
```

Now I want to know: How can I simply display the posts which are loaded by Redux, in my Home.jsx file.
And after that: How can I configure the route and data, to go to a single post (but that will come later, for now I only want to know an easy but right way how to display the posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea about the structure of your Post object. But it should be something like this.

```
renderPosts() {
  return _.map(this.props.posts, post => {
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={post.id}>
          {post.title}
      </li>
    );
  });
}
```

Then in your render method merely call it like this.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Posts</h3>
        <ul className="list-group">
          {this.renderPosts()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Also notice that I am using `map` helper from `lodash` library here. So you need to have following import statement in your component.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented you combineReducers correctly then mapStateToPosts should be called with set of posts when it is changed.

```
import posts from './posts_reducer';

combineReducers({ posts });
```

To render posts in your `Home` component you need to modify the render function, see raw implementation below:

```
render() {
    let postsElements = this.props.posts.map(p => {
        return <div>p.title</div>
    });
    return(
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <main>
              <h1>Home</h1>
            </main>
            <div>
                {postsElements}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

You need to use `this.props.posts` to access your posts because **react-redux** maps properties from state to props object of the component using mapStateToProps function that is provided as a 1st argument when calling `connect` function.

To improve this you can implement you Blog component and replace `div` with that.

Also, review how it is implemented in the example you provided https://github.com/jackreichert/a-wp-react-redux-theme/blob/master/src/components/main.js in this file posts are rendered.

Comment: I've updated my question, because I'm getting the 'This.props.posts.map() is not a function' when I try this aswell

Comment: @coder14 can you provide a jsfiddle where this issue reproduces? Looks like this.props.posts is undefined when component is rendering.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; // glue between react and redux
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';

class BlogPosts extends Component {
  render() {
    if (!this.props.posts) {
      return (<div></div>);
    }
    return (
     <div className="blog-items" >
        <ListGroup>
          {this.renderBlogPosts()}
        </ListGroup>
     </div>
    )
  };
  renderBlogPosts() {
    if (this.props.posts.posts) { //v1
      const posts = this.props.posts.posts; // DRY
      return posts.map((post, index) => {
        const excerptText = JSON.stringify(post.excerpt);
        const excerpt = excerptText.substring(1, excerptText.length-3);
        return (
          <LinkContainer className="blog-posts-link" key={post.ID} to={ "/blog/post/" + post.ID + '/'}>
            { this.getHtml(
              post.ID,
              (post.featured_image) ? post.featured_image : '',
              post.title,
              excerpt 
            )}
          </LinkContainer>
        );
      });
    };
    const posts = this.props.posts; // DRY
    return posts.map((post, index) => { // v2
      return (
        <div key={post.id}>
          {this.getHtml(
            post.id, 
            (post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']) 
              ? post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url : '',
            post.title.rendered,
            post.excerpt.rendered
          )}
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
  getHtml(id, imageSrc, title, excerpt) {
    return (
      <ListGroupItem className="blog-posts-list-item">
        {this.getImage(imageSrc, title)}
        <h2 className="blog-posts-title">{ Parser(title) }</h2>
        <div className="blog-posts-excerpt">{Parser(excerpt)}</div>
      </ListGroupItem>
    );   
  };
  getImage(imageSrc, title) {
    return (imageSrc === "") 
      ? (<div></div>) 
      : (<div className="blog-posts-image-div">
          <Image className="blog-posts-image" src={imageSrc} alt={title} />
        </div>
      );
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ posts: state.posts });
export default connect(mapStateToProps) (BlogPosts);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Please read why [it isn't wise to post code-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/341145)